# gcc configure, set defaults?

Tags: gcc, makefile, environment-variables, configure

When I run gcc configure, e.g

```
./configure
```

I do it like this

```
./configure \
    --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 \
    --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw/sys-root/mingw
```

Is there a way to make these settings the default, for all invokations of `configure`? Perhaps an environment variable?

Comment: Probably better than an environment variable would be a bash alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `configure` scripts generated with Autoconf, there is indeed a facility using the [environment variable `CONFIG_SITE`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Site-Defaults.html).

Use `export CONFIG_SITE=/path/to/my.config.site`, where the contents of that file are a script along the lines of

```
test -z "$host_alias" && host_alias=x86_64-w64-mingw32
test "$prefix" = NONE && prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw/sys-root/mingw
```